# JQuery UI Autosuggest not displaying items immediately

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

JQuery sends request and I see the response (via Firebug) with NO ERRORS.  But for one or two characters the results are not being displayed in the drop down.  Usually on the second character typed the results start showing (and I am typing slowly, 1 character per second or so, just to test if it was a speed issue of some sort).

Here is an example of the req/resp from firebug, at this point the items are not being displayed on the page:

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":1,
    "params":{
      "fl":"title,count",
      "sort":"count desc",
      "indent":"on",
      "start":"0",
      "q":"\"b\" AND count:[3 TO *]",
      "wt":"json",
      "rows":"5",
      "version":"2.2"}},
  "response":{"numFound":6536,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
        "title":"blood",
        "count":19890},
      {
        "title":"biochemistry",
        "count":14480},
      {
        "title":"biochemical and biophysical research communications",
        "count":6976},
      {
        "title":"businessweek",
        "count":6498},
      {
        "title":"biochimica et biophysica acta",
        "count":6226}]
  }}
```

Again, as I said, the console shows no errors on page.

Any thoughts as to how I should pursue this issue?

The Javascript code is:

```
function autosuggest(term, wid)
{
    var query = "q=" + escape(term);
    var url = "/autosuggest.do?" + query;

    $.getJSON(url, function(terms)
    {
        // iterate over terms

        var list = new Array();

        if (terms.response != null && terms.response.docs != null) {
            for(var i=0; i < terms.response.docs.length; i++)
            {
                var trm = terms.response.docs[i];
                list[i] = trm.title;
            }
            $( '#' + wid ).autocomplete({source: list, select: function(event, ui) { 
                doSuggestedSearch(ui.item.value);
            }});
        }
    });
}
```

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: When you look at the data in Firebug (or other development console) does the data look as you expect for each request?

Answer (score 1):

autosuggest has a delay option, defaulted to 300ms, which you can override:

`$( ".selector" ).autocomplete({ delay: 0 });`

Comment: Thank you for your response!  Yes, the default is 300 milliseconds tho'...  Also, minLength defaults to 1.  I tried setting it to 0 to no avail.  I did try setting delay to 0 as well but it too made no difference.  It's strange behavior (to me).  I would think maybe it was some sort of lag but I can see the server responding immediately to the queries as I type.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems to be working fine in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/william/Z7bcQ/

Was there any concurrent requests or heavy processing? I suggest you to somehow profile your page and find the bottleneck. Firebug has a [profiler](http://getfirebug.com/javascript) in the console tab. Safari also comes with a nice profiler in its Web Inspector.

Comment: The profiler... yes that is a good idea!  I didn't think of that.